# Handbrake encodes forever

Tags: encoding, handbrake

I'm trying to encode a movie (there are four different movies on the disk, two on each side of a DVD) and about half way through Handbrake gets stuck, and encodes forever.  If I stop it and skip toward the end of the file, its the same few frame repeating until the end of the video.  This is what the log tells me:

```
x264 [info]: profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[19:10:45] sync: first pts video is 0
[19:10:45] sync: "Chapter 1" (1) at frame 1 time 0
[19:10:45] sync: first pts audio 0x80bd is 0
[19:13:14] sync: "Chapter 2" (2) at frame 10131 time 30420390
[19:17:37] sync: "Chapter 3" (3) at frame 27309 time 82005924
[19:20:45] sync: "Chapter 4" (4) at frame 39569 time 118822704
[19:26:51] sync: "Chapter 5" (5) at frame 57033 time 171267096
[19:30:48] sync: "Chapter 6" (6) at frame 71138 time 213624411
[19:35:02] sync: "Chapter 7" (7) at frame 87440 time 262579317
[19:39:10] sync: video time went backwards 433 ms, dropped 13 frames. PTS 311876565
[19:39:10] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 311921958
[19:39:10] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 311965158
[19:39:11] sync: video time went backwards 467 ms, dropped 14 frames. PTS 312008697
[19:39:11] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312051558
[19:39:11] sync: video time went backwards 467 ms, dropped 14 frames. PTS 312094758
[19:39:11] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312137958
[19:39:11] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312181158
[19:39:12] sync: video time went backwards 967 ms, dropped 29 frames. PTS 312191880
[19:39:12] sync: video time went backwards 33 ms, dropped 1 frames. PTS 312247161
[19:39:12] sync: video time went backwards 934 ms, dropped 28 frames. PTS 312274743
[19:39:13] sync: video time went backwards 467 ms, dropped 14 frames. PTS 312397866
[19:39:13] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312440358
[19:39:13] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312483558
[19:39:13] sync: video time went backwards 467 ms, dropped 14 frames. PTS 312526995
[19:39:13] sync: video time went backwards 500 ms, dropped 15 frames. PTS 312569958
```

And the time backwards messges repeat until the messge that I canceled the encoding.  So clearly something is wrong with the source, which was copied from the DVD to the HD using AnyDVD.

Is there any way to get past this?  Should I try to DVD copy again, or is there some way to clean it up to all it to encode?

Comment: Try copying the dvd again with MakeMKV. Has always worked well for me.

Comment: If encoding to AVI, try encoding to MKV instead. You may also try another converter than Handbrake, for example VLC.

Comment: Try asking over at their community forum: https://forum.handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to download MakeMKV and open the IFO file in the VIDEO_TS folder AnyDVD created and it just copied the data to an MKV for me.  Just had to uncheck the other movie & menu tracks, and specify the output directory and file name.  It found the same errors, but I believe it just dropped those frames.